# Make child divs inside a parent div equal width and fluid

Tags: html, css

How can I make the 3 child `div`with class `.box` have the same `width` while fluidly occupying the entire parent `container` `div` while staying `inline`.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8s141njq/)

```css
#container {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can use flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Comment: or display:table/table-cell

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use **CSS flexbox** for that

```css
#container {
  width: 20em;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

use `inline-block` as you already are using, with a few tweaks.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
#container {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  text-align:center
}
.box {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">test</div><div class="box">test</div><div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

use **CSS tables** for old browsers support

```css
#container {
  width: 20em;
  display: table;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display:table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

display:table version:

```css
#container {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 1em;
  /* instead the margin:1em; you applied to children */
}
.box {
  display: table-cell;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.middle{vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>

</div>
<hr/>
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">test
    <br/>+ 1line ?</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box middle">test</div>

</div>
```

`table-layout:fixed` will fix width value you set, for main container and children.

**if children(table-cell) have no width set, they will spray evenly**

```css
#container {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 1em;
  /* instead the margin:1em; you applied to children */
}
.box {
  display: table-cell;
  ;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.middle{vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box">test test test test </div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>

</div>
<hr/>
<div id="container"class=" bis ">

  <div class="box">testtesttesttest testtesttest</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>
  <div class="box">test</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with `display: inline-block` you can set equal width of `33.33%` on each `.box`, remove white space from `HTML` and also add `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  width: 20em;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">test</div><div class="box">test</div><div class="box">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you forgot the margin:1em from its original fiddle :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. All of your answers are correct but I will have to choose an answer so I'll have to give it to highest vote.